# Changing characters on the console depending on user keystrokes

Tags: c#, console

What I want to do is to to change the console depending on what the user has pressed.

So I have a console with three options like this:

```
>  Option 1

Option 2

Option 3
```

Basically, if the user presses the down arrow, the console becomes like this:

```
Option 1

>  Option 2

Option 3
```

And if the user presses the up arrow, the console goes back to it's initial state.

I know how to read the user's input with Console.ReadKey(), but I don't know how to modify output that is already written.

One last thing is that when the user presses enter, the console does not create a new line, but chooses one of the options and calls a delegate.

Comment: Hi, what you probably want to to is [Console.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.clear) and then write the output again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too difficult to achieve using `Console.ReadKey` and some variables to hold the state of the selected option.

The following code is a very quick and lazy implementation of what you are looking for.  Take the time to rewrite it yourself properly - this is to give you an idea of how you could achieve what you are looking for.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool IsRunning = true;
    int Selected = 1;

    while (IsRunning)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo NextKey = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

        if (Selected < 1)
            Selected = 3;
        else if (Selected > 3)
            Selected = 1;

        Console.Clear();
        if (Selected == 1)
            Console.Write("> ");
        Console.WriteLine("Option 1");
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (Selected == 2)
            Console.Write("> ");
        Console.WriteLine("Option 2");
        Console.WriteLine();
        if (Selected == 3)
            Console.Write("> ");
        Console.WriteLine("Option 3");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Choose an option (Q to Quit): ");

        while (!(NextKey.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow ||
                NextKey.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow ||
                NextKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Q ||
                (NextKey.KeyChar >= '1' &&
                NextKey.KeyChar <= '3')))
        {
            NextKey = Console.ReadKey();
        }

        switch (NextKey.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
                // Do something
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D2:
                // Do something
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D3:
                // Do something
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                Selected++;
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                Selected--;
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.Q:
                IsRunning = false;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code will loop whilst the 'Q' key has not been pushed to quit the application.

Pushing the down or up arrow will rotate through the options available.

Upon pushing 1, 2, or 3, you will cause the `// Do something` lines inside the `switch` statement to be run.  You should here call whatever functionality exists for each of the options.

In order to update the 'menu' with the chosen option, the console output is cleared and then re-output.  The correct option is identified via the `Selected` variable.

There are several other ways to implement the above, some much tidier.  I wanted to give you an idea of where to start.  I am not saying that this is the best or most tidy solution.

**EDIT**

A thought occurs - you wanted to use Enter to select the option.

I've modified the code a little to provide that functionality:

```
    while (!(NextKey.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow ||
            NextKey.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow ||
            NextKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Q ||
            NextKey.Key ==  ConsoleKey.Enter))
    {
        NextKey = Console.ReadKey();
    }

    switch (NextKey.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.Enter:
            // Do something depending on Selected option
            switch (Selected)
            {
                case 1:
                    // Do something
                    break;

                case 2:
                    // Do something
                    break;

                case 3:
                    // Do something
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
        ...
```

Comment: You could use `Console.SetCursorPosition()` if you wanted to overwrite the existing output, instead of clearing the screen every time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar approach with a little less code, which hides the cursor and shows our own custom cursor that indicates the selected menu item.

The method takes in a menu header, a list of options for the user to select from, and a cursor character. It prints out the header and an underline, and then each option with 3 spaces before each one. Then we move the cursor to the first option (row index 3 since the header is 0, underline is 1, and blank space is 2), second character, and write a backspace character followed by our cursor (the backspace erases the first character so we can write a new one).

As the user presses keys, we only handle the up and down arrows and the enter key. By passing `true` to `Console.ReadKey()`, the user input is "thrown away" and not displayed on the window. This allows us to `switch` on only the keys we care about.

When they press an arrow key we move the cursor to the second column in the current row, print a backspace and then a space (to erase the old cursor), then move up or down one row, and from the second column we print a backspace and then our cursor character.

When the user presses `Enter`, we enable the console cursor again and return the row that the cursor was on to indicate which item was selected at that time:

```
private static int GetMenuChoice(string header, List<string> options, char cursor = '>')
{
    // Clear console and hide cursor
    Console.Clear();
    Console.CursorVisible = false;

    // Write our header with an underline
    Console.WriteLine("   " + header);
    Console.WriteLine("   " + new string('-', header.Length));
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Write out each option with spaces before it
    options.ForEach(option => Console.WriteLine($"   {option}"));

    // Move to the first option and, from the second character,
    // write a backspace and then the cursor symbol
    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 3);
    Console.Write($"\b{cursor}");

    // Move cursor when user presses arrow keys, and get selection when they press enter
    while (true)
    {
        // Pass 'true' to ReadKey so the input is not written
        var input = Console.ReadKey(true);

        switch (input.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                if (Console.CursorTop > 3)
                {
                    Console.CursorLeft = 1;
                    Console.Write("\b ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                    Console.Write($"\b{cursor}");
                }
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                if (Console.CursorTop < options.Count + 2)
                {
                    Console.CursorLeft = 1;
                    Console.Write("\b ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, Console.CursorTop + 1);
                    Console.Write($"\b{cursor}");
                }
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                var selection = Console.CursorTop - 3;
                Console.CursorVisible = true;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, options.Count + 4);
                return selection;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be tested out with a sample ATM menu:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var options = new List<string>
    {
        "Open a new account",
        "Deposit Money",
        "Withdraw money",
        "Check balance",
        "Exit"
    };

    var selectedItem = GetMenuChoice("ATM Machine", options);

    Console.WriteLine($"You selected option: '{options[selectedItem]}'");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]